# Kivy ScrollView breaking layout of screen

Tags: python, kivy

So i'm making a program that will have a bunch of labels connected to one gridlayout. I want a few of these labels to be "under" the screen so that you can scroll down to it. However, I am having trouble with keeping the formatting of what I have currently and scrolling at the same time.

Below is what I want, with the "stuff7" label being under the screen. However I am unable to scroll.[Image of non-scrollable screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mj05.png)

However, I noticed when I put `size_hint_y: None` I am able to scroll but it messes up my formatting completely.
[Messed up format but able to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PLM5.png)

Below is my MRE
KV code

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<HomeScreen>:
FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos:  self.pos
    ScrollView:
        size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            rows: 6
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: self.minimum_width


            Label:
                text:"stuff1"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18

            Label:
                text:"stuff2"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18
            Label:
                text:"stuff3"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18

            Label:
                text:"stuff4"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18

            Label:
                text:"stuff5"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18

            Label:
                text:"stuff6"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18

            Label:
                text:"stuff7"
                color: "black"
                size_hint: 1,.18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `height: self.minimum_height` for the `GridLayout`, then you cannot use `size_hint: 1,.18` for the `Labels`. The `GridLayout` is trying to change its `height` based on the `height` of its children (the `Labels`). But the `Labels` are trying to set their `height` based on the `height` of the `GridLaout`. Try modifying  the `Labels` as:

```
        Label:
            text:"stuff2"
            color: "black"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Comment: I modified the labels as you did, however the formatting was a bit weird. I found myself manually changing ```self.minimum_height``` to a number which kept my formatting. Is there another value that would be better than ```self.minimum_height```?

Comment: You should leave the `self.minimum_height` alone in the `GridLayout` and assign heights to the `Labels`.

Comment: Ok that worked, keeping ```size_hint: 1, None``` and giving each ```label``` a ```height``` value it work. If you can, you can edit your response to include manually putting heights in for the labels for future reference. Thanks!